# In a batch script, how do I get the long name of a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

How do I get the long path of a file or directory?

I need a path to the temporary directory that doesn't have a `~` in it.

`%TEMP%` resolves to `C:\Users\YKAGAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp`

How do I obtain `C:\Users\ykaganovich\AppData\Local\Temp` ?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Theoretically, I think rundll32 should be able to handle it (using the GetLongPathName entry point in whichever DLL it's in - I've used it but never needed to know whether it was kernel32 or shell32 or something else).

Answer (score 1):

Try [this program](http://www.mediafire.com/?ylo2rkmn43rczw8) I just wrote.

Source ([D](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/)):

```c
import core.stdc.wchar_, core.sys.windows.windows;
extern (C) int __wgetmainargs(out int pargc, out wchar** pargv, out wchar** penvp, int dowildcard, out int startinfo);
extern (Windows) BOOL Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(out void* OldValue);
extern (Windows) HMODULE LoadLibraryW(in LPCWSTR lpFileName);
extern (Windows) DWORD GetLongPathNameW(in LPCWSTR lpszShortPath, LPWSTR lpszLongPath, in DWORD cchBuffer);
pragma(startaddress, wmainCRTStartup);
pragma(lib, "msvcrt.lib");
void* disableWow64Redirection()
{
    auto pKernel32 = LoadLibraryW("kernel32.dll");
    void* old;
    auto fn = cast(typeof(&Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection))GetProcAddress(cast(HMODULE)pKernel32, "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection");
    if (fn != null) { if (!fn(old)) { } }
    else { old = null; }
    FreeLibrary(pKernel32);
    return old;
}
int wmainCRTStartup()
{
    disableWow64Redirection();
    int argc, si; wchar** wargv, wenvp;
    __wgetmainargs(argc, wargv, wenvp, 0, si);
    wchar[32 * 1024] buffer = void; //big enough for all valid paths
    foreach (i; 1 .. argc)
    {
        auto len = GetLongPathNameW(wargv[i], buffer.ptr, buffer.length - 1);
        buffer.ptr[len] = '\0';
        if (i > 1) { wprintf(" "); }
        wprintf("%s", len > 0 ? buffer.ptr : wargv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
name <short-name>
```

---

What the heck, here's a C version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
typedef BOOL (WINAPI * PWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection)(void** OldValue);
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *wargv[])
{
    int i;
    wchar_t buffer[32 * 1024]; //big enough for all valid paths
    PWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection fn =
        (PWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection)GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandle(_T("kernel32.dll")), "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection");
    if (sizeof(size_t) > 4 && fn != NULL) //Remove if WOW64 wanted
    { void* old; Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&old); }
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        DWORD len = GetLongPathNameW(wargv[i], buffer, ARRAYSIZE(buffer) - 1);
        buffer[len] = _T('\0');
        if (i > 1) { wprintf(_T(" ")); }
        wprintf(_T("%s"), len > 0 ? buffer : wargv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd prefer a solution in batch, but I'll keep this in mind... Also, does it work on all 64-bit Windows (XP, Vista, 7)? I presume `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` won't work on a 32-bit OS? (yes, I realize there's no `Program Files (x86)` on 32-bit OS, but currently my script doesn't care about the OS; it just looks for the file in all possible known locations, of which that is one).

Comment: @ykaganovich: It will give you the correct result on 32-bit systems, and a 64-bit result on 64-bit systems. It will *not* get redirected on 64-bit systems (because I use `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`), even if it's called by a 32-bit command prompt, so be careful about that. There's no problem on 32-bit systems because I only call `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` if the function actually exists.

Comment: @ykaganovich: I've posted a C version too, but I didn't use it originally because my compilers seem to kind of make the executable bloated with references to other functions and DLLs, introducing more dependencies than necessary; if you want a native 64-bit version, though, you'll need to compile the C version.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Updated solution using `for /r /d` as suggested by Joey:

This is a pretty greedy way to do it, but it works:

```
pushd c:\

for /r /d %%D in (.) do (
    if /i %%~sD equ %TMP% (
        @echo %%~dpfD
        popd
        exit /b
    )
)
```

- First `pushd c:\` to make `c:\` the starting point of the search.
- `for /r /d (.)` will walk the directory tree.
- We loop through the list of directories comparing the short name (`%%~sD`) to the name in the variable `TMP`. If they're equal we print out the expanded long name, restore the original working directory, and exit the script.
- Needed to use `%%dpfD` rather than `%%D`; for some reason `%%D` had `\.` tacked on to the end of the path name.
- I tried using `if %%~sD==%TMP%` at first, but it didn't work.

I tested this in WindowsXP and Windows 7 and works on both. Takes a while to run, but eventually gets the job done.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're iterating over the output of `dir` instead of just using `for /r /d` directly?

Comment: @Joey; good idea, I didn't think of that. I'm so used to using `for` with `/f` I always forget about using `/r /d`.

Comment: The problem with iterating over `dir` output is that it fails with Unicode file names and Raster fonts in the console. It might not hit that many people in the US, but for me it's fairly common :-)